# Open custom single post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, singleton, customization, custom-post-type

I am writing below this code and create file **single-course.php** but not work. Please help me
**I am refreshing my permalink.**

Please help me
Please help me
Please help me

```
<?php
function register_custom_post() {
          register_post_type( 'course', 
               array(
               'labels'=> array(
                    'menu_name'         => __( 'Courses', 'course' ),
                    'name'               => __( 'All Courses', 'Course' ),
                    'singular_name'      => __( 'Course', 'Course' ),
                    

                ),
               'public'              => false,
               'show_ui'             => true,
               'show_in_rest'        => true,
               'supports'            => 
                    array(
                         'title',
                         'editor',
                         'author',
                         'thumbnail',
                         'excerpt',
                         'custom-fields',
                         'trackbacks',
                         'comments',
                         'revisions',
                         'page-attributes',
                         'post-formats',
                    ),
               )
          );
     }
     
     add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post' );
     
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also understand [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'course',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'numberposts'      => 1 //number of posts you want to get
             );
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: I'm already use this query and while loop in single.php but not show my single.php layout